# Manage darktable tags from command-line

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to read image tags from darktable from command-line, i.e. something like `darktable --get-tags myimage.jpg` would return all tags of this image.

How can I tag an image or modify the tags from command-line such that the tags are integrated into the darktable database?

**Edit**

darktable seems to use xmp sidecar files and tags are in the xmp sidecar file like

```
<dc:subject>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li>myTag1</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>myTag2</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </dc:subject>
   <lr:hierarchicalSubject>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li>myTag1</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li>myTag2</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </lr:hierarchicalSubject>
```

However I don't see how to read, set and modify it from commandline. My first thought was to use `sed` or `awk` but those are for things in one singe line.

Another approach would be to read and write directly to the darktable database, which is used additionally to the xmp files.

**Edit2** 
I just realized that `exiftool` can set tags of xmp sidecar files: For example

```
exiftool -Subject=myNewTag myimage.jpg.xmp
exiftool -`Hierarchical*Subject*`=myNewTag myimage.jpg.xmp
```

deletes all tags and sets `myNewTag` as the only tag. Or

```
exiftool -Subject+=myAdditionalTag myimage.jpg.xmp
exiftool -`Hierarchical*Subject*`+=myAdditionalTag myimage.jpg.xmp
```

adds the tag `myAdditionalTag` to the list of tags.

Then I checked the option [`look for updated xmp files on startup`](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/core_options.html) in darktable and hoped that it would update the tags while reload. However even if I deleted the old tags as in the first case, darktable shows me the newtag *and* the old (removed) tags.

So this doesn't seem the way to go.